# AWS Cognito & Flask app can't grab the jwt from the url

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-cognito

I have this simple Flask app, when you visit the landing page it redirects you to AWS Cognito  portal where you login and then you get redirect to a webpage with a jwt in url. I am trying to get the jwt from the url but with no luck.

Everything works fine,

- I visit the app(localy)
- I get redirected to AWS Cognito portal
- I login & redirected to the flask app
- There I try to get the jwt but with no luck

Here's the code and what I've tried so far

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def landing_page():
    print('*' * 20)
    print(request.args)
    print(request.data.decode('UTF-8'))
    print(request.get_json())
    print(request.values)
    print(request.json)
    print(request.headers)
    print(request.headers.get('#id_token'))
    print(request.headers.get('id_token'))
    print(request.get_data().decode('UTF-8'))
    print(request.get_data())
    print(request.stream.read().decode('UTF-8'))
    print(request.args.get('id_token'))
    print(request.stream.read())
    print(request.args.to_dict([]))
    print(request.args.to_dict())
    print(request.args.get('id_token'))
    try:
        print(request.args['id_token'])
    except:
        print('pass')
    print('*' * 20)
    return redirect('https://xxx.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/',
                    code=302)
```

And the results

```sh
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Mar/2021 08:35:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
********************
ImmutableMultiDict([])

None
CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([])])
None
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xxxx Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _xsrf=2|xxx|xxx|xxxx


None
None

b''

None
b''
{}
{}
pass
None
********************
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Mar/2021 08:35:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon Cognito sets the `code` query string in your URL when it redirects to your application.

For example, if I configure my Amazon Cognito App Client redirect URL to `http://localhost:5000/cognito_redirect`, I'll have:

```
http://localhost:5000/cognito_redirect?code=bd5xxxxx-xxx5-xx1f-97xx-xxxxx3exxxx7
```

you can retrieve it from the URL like:

```py
@app.route('/cognito_redirect')
def cognito_redirect():
  print(request.args.get('code'))
```

Logging the following:

```
bd5xxxxx-xxx5-xx1f-97xx-xxxxx3exxxx7
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Mar/2021 23:23:02] "GET /cognito_redirect?code=bd5xxxxx-xxx5-xx1f-97xx-xxxxx3exxxx7 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

More details about the `request` object can be found in the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#the-request-object).

#### Update 2021-03-27

Hey folks, I created a working example with AWS CloudFormation for the Amazon Cognito User Pool (explicitly showing which configurations you can use) + A sample Flask app with a single route

https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/2021-03-27-flask-with-cognito

You can check the instructions in the README to how to deploy it and some details about the requirements for the OAuth redirect in Cognito.

**THIS IS NOT** an exhaustive list of configurations for Amazon Cognito, there's many more ways to configure it, but, it is showing the minimum that you need to have OAuth working.

I do have another example with Node.js here:

https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/node-amazon-cognito-oauth

Comment: print(request.args.get('code')) returned None, also my url query redirect string from cognito is very different. But even if I adjust with the right parameters for the right response the printed value is still None. Is it possible to share more code of your project?

Comment: How you have set cognito on aws?

Comment: Can you share the url you are getting?

Comment: @miquelvir right now I don't have the exact url but it's something like this `'https://xxx.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/#id_token=xxxxxx` and some other queries. I don't know where he got the code parameter, there isn't anything like code in that query, even including code or anything like that.

Comment: Okey, I have submitted an answer having seen this!

Comment: hello folks, I have updated my answer to include a working example with CloudFormation for the Amazon Cognito and a Flask app

Comment: I just saw your answer and the time had expired. I am going to check the repo and let you know

Comment: I couldn't make it work but your approach although is different from what I initially tried to approach seems in the right path. Also kudos for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

From the posted link, notice that the id_token you seem to be interested is a parameter of the redirect_uri, not of the main url. So you need to get the redirect url, and parse it to get the id_token from it.

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

@app.route('/')
def landing_page():
    try:
        redirect_url = request.args['redirect_uri']
        print(redirect_url)
        parsed = urlparse.urlparse(redirect_url)
        id_token = parse_qs(parsed.query)['id_token']
        print(id_token)
    except:
        print('pass')
    return redirect('https://xxx.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/',
                    code=302)
```

Comment: I am not getting an error, I am getting a pass. Also I've tried with `#id_token` but still the same

Comment: well you are getting a pass because there is an error, try removing the except to see what error you have

Comment: Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: please provide the full stack trace

Comment: There is no stack trace, I just get a bad request on the web browser and on flask app just 
`127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2021 16:35:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2021 16:35:07] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -`